# Test the surrounding non-zeros elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

This is the following part of the below:

2) **Additional question:**

After getting the average of the non-zero neighbors, I also want to test if the neighbor elements are equal, lesser, or greater  than the average of the nonzeros. If it is greater or equal then '1' or else '0'.

Note: if the neighbors are with in the radius of the two or more centres,  take the smallest centre average to test.

```
    0    12     9     
    4  **9**    15     
   11    19     0
```

The '9' in the middle is within the radius of 12, 15, and 19 centres, so take the minimum average of those min[9.000, 9.000, 8.000]=8.000

For example, when radius = 1 m or 1 element away.

new_x =

```
     0         0          0          0         0
     0         0     **9.0000**    9.0000      0
     0      4.0000     9.0000    **9.0000**    0
     0    **8.3333** **8.0000**      0         0
     0      2.0000     4.0000      8.0000      0
     0      4.0000     5.0000      8.0000      0
     0         0          0          0         0
```

Test_x =

```
     0         0           0           0         0
     0         0       **9.0000**      1         0
     0         0           1       **9.0000**    0
     0    **8.3333**   **8.0000**      0         0
     0         0           0           0         0
     0         0           0           0         0
     0         0           0           0         0
```

=================================================================================

1) Say if I have a matrix, shown as below,

X =

```
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0    12     9     0
 0     4     9    15     0
 0    11    19     0     0
 0     2     4     8     0
 0     4     5     8     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

and I want to find the average of the surrounding non-zero elements that is greater than 10. The rest of the elements still remain the same i.e. elements < 10.

So I want my solution to look something like,

new_x =

```
     0         0         0         0         0
     0         0    9.0000    9.0000         0
     0    4.0000    9.0000    9.0000         0
     0    8.3333    8.0000         0         0
     0    2.0000    4.0000    8.0000         0
     0    4.0000    5.0000    8.0000         0
     0         0         0         0         0
```

Not: that I am **NOT** only looking at the neighbors of the element thats greather than some value (i.e. 10 in this case).

Lets say any elements thats are greater than 10 are the 'centre' and we want to find the avearge of the non-zeros with the radius of say 1 m. where 1 metre = 1 element away from the centre.

Note: It might not always be 1 meter away in radius i.e. can be 2 or more. In this case it wont be just top, bottom, left and right of the centre.

****Also Be aware of the matrix boundary. For example, when radius = 2 or more, some of the average of nonzero neighbors are out side the boundary.**

For example,

For radius =1 m = 1 element away,
new_x = average of [(i+1,j) , (i-1,j) , (i,j+1) and (i,j-1)] - top, bottom, right, and left of the centre.

For radius =2 m = 2 elements away,
new_x = average of [(i+1,j), (i+2,j) , (i-1,j) , (i-2,j), (i,j+1), (i,j+2), (i,j-1), (i,j-2), (i+1,j+1), (i+1,j-1), (i-1,j-1), and (i-1,j+1)].

==================================================================

I have tried a few things before, however I am not familiar with the functions.

So please help me to solve the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the algorithm I think you are describing in your question. For each pixel:

- If the pixel value is less than 10, do nothing.
- If the pixel value is greater than or equal to 10, replace the pixel value by the average of the non-zero 4-connected nearest neighbors.

If this is correct (as it appears to be from the sample matrices you gave), then you could use the function [NLFILTER](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/nlfilter.html) from the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/) (if you have access to it) to perform this operation:

```
fcn = @(x) [x(5) sum(x(2:2:8))/max(sum(x(2:2:8) > 0),1)]*[x(5) < 10; x(5) >= 10];
new_x = nlfilter(X,[3 3],fcn);
```

**EDIT:** If you don't have access to the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/), you can also do this using the built-in [CONV2](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/conv2.html) function, like so:

```
kernel = [0 1 0; ...                      %# Convolution kernel
          1 0 1; ...
          0 1 0];
sumX = conv2(X,kernel,'same');            %# Compute the sum of neighbors
                                          %#   for each pixel
nX = conv2(double(X > 0),kernel,'same');  %# Compute the number of non-zero
                                          %#   neighbors for each pixel
index = (X >= 10);                        %# Find logical index of pixels >= 10
new_x = X;                                %# Initialize new_x
new_x(index) = sumX(index)./max(nX(index),1);  %# Replace the pixels in index
                                               %#   with the average of their
                                               %#   non-zero neighbors
```

The above handles your radius = 1 case. To address your radius = 2 case, you just have to change the convolution kernel to the following and rerun the above code:

```
kernel = [0 0 1 0 0; ...
          0 1 1 1 0; ...
          1 1 0 1 1; ...
          0 1 1 1 0; ...
          0 0 1 0 0];
```

Comment: Does this also work with when radius = 2 m??

For radius =2 m = 2 elements away, new_x = average of [(i+1,j), (i+2,j) , (i-1,j) , (i-2,j), (i,j+1), (i,j+2), (i,j-1), (i,j-2), (i+1,j+1), (i+1,j-1), (i-1,j-1), and (i-1,j+1)].

Thanks again.

Comment: @user327950: Yes, it can work if you make a few changes. You would have to replace `[3 3]` with `[5 5]`, `x(5)` with `x(13)`, and `x(2:2:8)` with `x([3 7:9 11 12 14 15 17:19 23])`.

Comment: Ohhhh thats great!! The problem now is that I dont have access to Image Processing Toolbox. Thank you for your help anyway. I am really appreciated.

Comment: @user327950: I updated my answer with another option that doesn't require any extra toolboxes.

Comment: I got this error saying that '??? Error using ==> conv2
First and second arguments must be single or double.' Why is that??

I have a 256*255 matrix with the radius of 11m. 

Thank you again.

Comment: @user327950: The inputs to [CONV2](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/conv2.html) have to be of type single or double. The function isn't written to handle integer or logical values, so you can convert inputs of those types to double precision using [DOUBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/double.html), like I did when computing `nX` in the above code.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**:
Note this requires functions from the Image Processing Toolbox, namely: [COLFILT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) and [STREL](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel-class.html)

```
r = 1;                       %# radius
t = 10;                      %# threshold value
mid = round((2*r+1)^2/2);    %# mid point
nhood = getnhood(strel('diamond', r));
nhood(mid) = false;
fcn = @(M)sum(M(nhood(:),:),1)./(sum(M(nhood(:),:)~=0)+all(M(nhood(:),:)==0)).*(M(mid,:)>=t)+M(mid,:).*(M(mid,:)<t);
new_x = colfilt(x, 2*[r r]+1, 'sliding',fcn)
```

For r=1:

```
new_x =
            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0            9            9            0
            0            4            9            9            0
            0       8.3333            8            0            0
            0            2            4            8            0
            0            4            5            8            0
            0            0            0            0            0
```

For r=2:

```
new_x =
            0            0            0            0            0
            0            0         11.2            9            0
            0            4            9       10.167            0
            0            7       7.7778            0            0
            0            2            4            8            0
            0            4            5            8            0
            0            0            0            0            0
```

In fact, it should work for any `radius >= 1`

Notice how the diamond shape structuring element represents the neighborhood:

```
nhood =
     0     1     0
     1     0     1
     0     1     0

nhood =
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0
     1     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0

and so on..
```

---

**Explanation:**

We use the [COLFILT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) function which traverse the matrix using a sliding neighborhood of NxN, and places each block as a column in a temporary matrix.

We process each column of this temp matrix (blocks) using the function `fcn`, and the result will be placed in the correct location once finished ([COLFILT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) uses [IM2COL](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) and [COL2IM](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/col2im.html) underneath).

We check for two cases depending of the value of the center of the block:

1. If its less than 10, it returns that value unchanged: `M(mid,:)`
2. if its >=10, we compute the mean of the non-zero elements of its neighborhood
   `sum(M(nhood(:),:),1) ./ (sum(M(nhood(:),:)~=0) + all(M(nhood(:),:)==0))`.
   The last term in there is necessary to avoid dividing by zero

Notice how the result of 1 & 2 above are combined using `R1.*(M(mid,:)<t) + R2.*(M(mid,:)>=t)` to emulate an if/else choice.

Comment: +1: Nice generalized solution, and good catch on the need for `all(M==0)` to avoid `NaN` values. However, I think you are using the entire matrix `M`, when the OP is only asking for nearest neighbors in `M`.

Comment: @gnovice: alright I think I got it now.. I'm using a diamond shape structuring element to get the neighborhood (just like the OP explained)

Comment: Thank you for the help Amro. However I couldnt use your method as I dont have  the Image Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this: (tested in Octave, should work in matlab)

```
octave-3.2.3:17> toohigh = (x>=10)
toohigh =

   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   1   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0

octave-3.2.3:18> nbr_avg = filter2(ones(3,3)/9,x)
nbr_avg =

   0.00000   1.33333   2.33333   2.33333   1.00000
   0.44444   2.77778   5.44444   5.00000   2.66667
   1.66667   6.11111   8.77778   7.11111   2.66667
   1.88889   5.44444   8.00000   6.11111   2.55556
   1.88889   5.00000   6.77778   4.88889   1.77778
   0.66667   1.66667   3.44444   2.77778   1.77778
   0.44444   1.00000   1.88889   1.44444   0.88889

octave-3.2.3:19> y=x; y(toohigh) = nbr_avg(toohigh)

y =

   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   5.44444   9.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   4.00000   9.00000   7.11111   0.00000
   0.00000   5.44444   8.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   2.00000   4.00000   8.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   4.00000   5.00000   8.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

The `filter2` function allows you to filter on neighbors (not sure what function you want...), and if you use a boolean index matrix (`toohigh` in this case) to select those members of the original matrix that are too high, you can replace them with the ones you want.

More specifically, filter2 allows you to convolve with an arbitrary matrix. The matrix of all ones does a spatial low pass filter.

---

note: my math doesn't match yours. I'm not quite sure why you want to average only the nonzero neighbors (that gives higher weight to nonzero neighbors when there are zeros), but if you wanted to do that, you could do `filter2(ones(3,3),x) ./ M` where `M  = filter2(ones(3,3),(x ~= 0))` is the count of nonzero neighbors.

Comment: Thank you for the idea Jason. However its not quite what I want to do. I am looking for NOT only the neighbors of the element thats greather than some value (i.e. 10 in this case). Lets say any elements thats are greater than 10 are the 'centre'. And we want to find the avearge of the non-zeros with the radius of say 1 m. Where 1 metre = 1 element away from the centre. As you mentioned that filter2 only allow you to filter the neigbours. what if I want to avearage further than just the neigbors i.e. 2 or more elements away from the centre. Thank you again.

Comment: just use a larger convolution matrix (e.g. 3x3)

Comment: p.s. you can use any pattern you want -- the convolution matrix [0 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0; 1 1 0 1 1; 0 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0] has 1's shaped like a cross and includes only the 2 nearest neighbors directly north/south/east/west.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Here is a solution that does not require the Image Processing Toolbox. It does, however, use `conv2nan.m` which is part of the free [NaN toolbox](http://www.dpmi.tu-graz.ac.at/~schloegl/matlab/NaN/).

This approach relies on doing two different filtering/convolution operations: one that gets the sum of surrounders for each element, and one that gets the count of nonzero surrounders. Then, you are ready to combine them to get the average of nonzero surrounders only. Like this:

```
% set up starting point matrix with some zeros
X = magic(4);
X(X < 5) = 0;

X(X == 0) = NaN; % convert zeros to NaNs to work with conv2nan
countmat = double(X > 0);

cmat = [0 1 0;
        1 0 1;
        0 1 0]; % consider surrounding elements only

[m1,c] = conv2nan(X,cmat); % sum of surrounding elements
[m2,c] = conv2nan(countmat,cmat); % number of surrounding elements > 0

x_new = m1./m2; % compute average we want

x_new = x_new(2:end-1,2:end-1); % trim edges created by conv2
x_new(~countmat) = 0; % restore zero elements
x_new(X < 10) = X(X < 10) % restore < 10 elements
```

It does some extra work in that the convolutions are done for all elements and not just those that are >= 10. But it's more general than the manual looping approach.

Comment: So for example, when there was 15 in [x], [new_x] = 9. i.e. (9+9)/2 = 9. first 9 is from the top of the 15 and the second 9 is from the left. Ignore the zeros at the bottom and on the right hand side of the 15. Hopefully this will help you to understand my problem better.

Comment: Can you please explain => [m1,c] = conv2nan(a,cmat).
I have an error saying 'undefined function or variable 'a'.
I have downloaded NaN toolbox.

Sorry I never use this function before.

Thanks again.

Comment: sorry, typo, should be X, fixed!

Comment: also some other edits because I forgot about changing >10 valued elements only. I think it's working correctly now. (and +1 for the awesome nlfilter find, which I didn't know about.)

Comment: Thank you for the help Matt. Does it also work when radius = 2 or more?? 

I have a 256*255 matrix and need to find the average of surrounding nonzeros in the radius of 11m.

Thank again.